# Why are foot and feet both "Fuss" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, noun, standard-german

Foot is singular, feet is plural. Why does Google translator fail to distinguish the difference and return "Fuss" for both?

Comment: Define “the translator”, please?

Comment: Why the downvotes? The fact that German, unlike English, does not pluralize measurement units is noteworthy.

Comment: @mach I didn't downvote the question, but it shows zero effort. People should at least try typing more than one word into their black boxes or magic machines; *my feet* would have sufficed to exclude the false premise. Strictly speaking, *why does the [unnamed] translator …* isn't even a question about the German language.

Comment: @user610620: While I don't agree that question should have been closed, I do agree that most of the criticisms were valid. In the future, it would be better to respond to such criticism by adding missing details or including information to clear up misunderstandings. The main point of the comments to help you frame the question to get the best chance of getting a useful answer, German speakers have a reputation, deserved or not, for being blunt about criticism. But it doesn't help to take offense and not try to improve what is being criticized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what's going on is that when you use *Fuß* as a unit of measurement then it's used in the singular. So *Er ist sechs Fuß groß* rather than *Er ist sechs Füße groß*. If you're using *Fuß* as a body part then it works as you would expect: *Er hat zwei Füße.* I don't know if there are other situations where "feet" would translate to *Fuß*, but this one seems likely, and if so the problem should resolve itself if you switch to the metric system.

BTW, just to head off comments from the spelling police, you're using Swiss spelling. I gather from our previous interactions that you're more familiar with Swiss Standard German than Standard German. Not that Swiss spelling is wrong, but it may raise some eyebrows here since Standard German spelling is more common.

Comment: The problem does not solve when switching to metric. Nearly generally units of measurement are singular irrespective how many you measure. The only exception which comes to my mind right now is "Unze" (ounce). Yet in English you "walk 250 metres to the next bus stop" while in German "Geh 250 Meter bis zur nächsten Bushaltestelle".

Comment: @planetmaker: Your last example does not really prove something, since singular and plural appear identical in nominative. I also observe dated *Ellen* as counter-example (5 Ellen Stoff)  as well as  *nach 300 Metern rechts abbiegen*.

Comment: Your assertion that “Standard German spelling is more common” than “Swiss spelling” makes me raise my eyebrows. You cannot oppose “Standard German” to “Swiss spelling”. Swiss spelling is as much Standard German as Germany German or Austrian spelling. Also, it is not true that non-Swiss spelling is more common. It depends on the location. In Switzerland, it is certainly not the case.

Comment: that's a good point @guidot. So indeed, essentially it's just that singular and plural nominative are the same, like 'Teller'.

Comment: @planetmaker: "The problem does not solve when switching to metric." - I suspect this was meant rather in the way that once you switch to metric, most commonly used units will be expressed by words that are fairly unambiguously units of measurement and nothing else. As opposed to a "foot".

Comment: @mach: I tried to specify "Standard German" spelling rather than "Standard spelling", meaning spelling according to the standards of German and Austria. It's confusing and almost certainly politically incorrect, but the name for the written language used in Germany and Austria is "Standard German", see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_German). (There are minor differences between German Standard German and Austrian Standard German, usually not noticeable though.)

Comment: @mach: ... The reason I brought it up is that we often get people who post questions, but don't use umlauts or the eszett. Sometimes it's because they haven't figured out how to do them on their keyboard but sometimes they can't be bothered. And sometimes such errors do draw the occasional comment. I happened to remember that the poster had asked questions about Swiss German before so I was trying to proactively prevent these comments. I agree there is nothing less "standard" about "Swiss Standard German". But, in my experience, most of regulars here do use eszetts.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: To be honest, I wasn't complete serious about the "switch to metric" remark. But my point (assuming there was one) was that if you're learning German then you should learn and use German measurements and not revert to feet, inches and pounds.

Comment: Well, on second thought, the question is not as simple as it sounds: While it is correct that German uses singular for measures in general, that wasn't true throughout history: "fünf Ellen Stoff", "sieben Meilen gehen", "zwei Unzen Gold". "Fuß" seems to be about the same age, so, the question should actually be "why is it 'fünf Fuß', but 'neun Ellen'"